# Jekyll Hooks for category gives "post['category'].reject { |t| t.empty? }" error

Tags: tags, jekyll, hook, categories

I am using `Hooks` for category and `tags` for my site. Following code for `tags` works just fine:

```rb
Jekyll::Hooks.register :posts, :post_write do |post|
  all_existing_tags = Dir.entries("./src/_tags")
    .map { |t| t.match(/(.*).md/) }
    .compact.map { |m| m[1] }

  tags = post['tags'].reject { |t| t.empty? }
  tags.each do |tag|
    generate_tag_file(tag) if !all_existing_tags.include?(tag)
  end
end

def generate_tag_file(tag)
  File.open("./src/_tags/#{tag}.md", "wb") do |file|
    file << "---\nlayout: tags\ntag-name: #{tag}\n---\n"
  end
end
```

But if I use similar code for `category` it doesn't:

```rb
Jekyll::Hooks.register :posts, :post_write do |post|
  all_existing_category = Dir.entries("./src/_category")
    .map { |t| t.match(/(.*).md/) }
    .compact.map { |m| m[1] }

  category = post['category'].reject { |t| t.empty? }
  category.each do |category|
    generate_category_file(category) if !all_existing_category.include?(category)
  end
end

def generate_category_file(category)
  File.open("./src/_category/#{category}.md", "wb") do |file|
    file << "---\nlayout: category\ncategory-name: #{category}\n---\n"
  end
end
```

I get the following error:

```
src/_plugins/category_generator.rb:6:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method `reject' for "test":String (NoMethodError)

  tags = post['category'].reject { |t| t.empty? }
```

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

I have tried it for `tags` but for `category` it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

From your the error you get, it seems like the issue comes from the type of `post['category']` , which is a string.

`post['tags']` is an array, and ruby arrays have a `reject` method. I'm guessing its elements are strings since you are calling `empty?`  on them.

Since you seem to expect a single category per post (as opposed to multiple tags per post) you should probably replace

```rb
category = post['category'].reject { |t| t.empty? }
category.each do |category|
  generate_category_file(category) if !all_existing_category.include?(category)
end
```

with something like

```rb
category = post['category'] 
generate_category_file(category) unless category.empty? || all_existing_category.include?(category)
```

This will deal with the case where `post['category']` is a string.

It is also possible that the types of `post['category']` and `post['tags']` are sometimes arrays and sometimes strings depending on what you put in your front matter. In this case, you should add a conditional statement in both your hooks to handle both cases (the array case in the same way you did, and the string case in the way I suggested)